# How to open an indirect buffer in a new frame in a single call in emacs?

Tags: emacs

There are a couple of functions to open a buffer in a new frame (`display-buffer-other-frame`, `switch-to-buffer-other-frame`), but how do I create an indirect buffer in a new frame (in a single call, that is)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

> **`clone-indirect-buffer-other-window`** is an interactive compiled Lisp
>   function in `simple.el`.
>
> It is bound to **`C-x 4 c`**.
>
> `(clone-indirect-buffer-other-window NEWNAME DISPLAY-FLAG &optional
>   NORECORD)`
>
> Like `clone-indirect-buffer` but display in another window.

Use `C-h f clone-indirect-buffer` to see details about what that command does.

---

OK, you want it opened in a separate **frame**, not just a separate Emacs **window**.  For that, you can define your own `clone-indirect-buffer-other-frame`, but just binding `pop-up-frames` to `t` around the call to `clone-indirect-buffer`, the same way that `clone-indirect-buffer-other-window` binds `pop-up-windows`.

```
(defun clone-indirect-buffer-other-frame (newname display-flag &optional norecord)
  "Like `clone-indirect-buffer' but display in another window."
  (interactive
   (progn
     (if (get major-mode 'no-clone-indirect)
     (error "Cannot indirectly clone a buffer in %s mode" mode-name))
     (list (if current-prefix-arg
           (read-buffer "Name of indirect buffer: " (current-buffer)))
       t)))
  ;; (let ((pop-up-windows t))
  (let ((pop-up-frames t)) ; <==========
    (clone-indirect-buffer newname display-flag norecord)))
```